# Xamarin Forms sync local database data with server

Tags: c#, synchronization, xamarin.forms

> I want to sync my local database data with server in Xamarin. I've
>   read about Microsoft Azure but I want to do it manually.
>    The way I'm
>   thinking to implement is to add a bool variable isSync to my data and
>   check the connectivity, when the device is connected to the internet I
>   will check my data, if isSync = false I'll send it to the server.

Is there any easier way to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to push local data to the server that is the easiest way to do that. I personally have used this approach in my projects and it works great.

If you also need to pull data from the server and store locally then it gets a bit trickier. You will want to define rules in the case the same record has been modified on the server and in your app, such as overwriting the local record or keeping it and discarding the data from the server. There is also the case where you will want to only pull the most recent added or edited records. In this case, using Azure Mobile Services would be easier since it handles most of these scenarios and you won´t need to implement all the logic manually. Here´s an overview of the topic: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-offline-data-sync